# How to connect multiple external databases in Magento?

Tags: database, database-connection, magento-1.9

I need to connect to some external databases from Magento. I found one tutorial to [Create an external database connection in Magento](http://fishpig.co.uk/create-an-external-database-connection-in-magento/). This tutorial was helpful and it worked for connecting to one external database. But, I have to connect more than one external databases.

How can I connect to more than one external databases (suppose 5 external databases) in Magento?

Comment: This type of question doesn't really belong on Stack Overflow, as it's not a programming question. You should take a look at http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/25439/magento and see about getting a proper place to put these kind of questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this one Magento Module that will help to connect to external database system. http://subesh.com.np/2012/02/magento-external-database-connector-v1-0-0-released/

I tried the module and seems to be working well.Hope this helps.

EDIT:

Module also available on Magento Connect. http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/sp-edb-4574.html

Comment: That link is dead now, do you have a fresh ULR? any follow-up comments on how this worked in live sites?

Answer (score 5):

I haven't tested it, but I would expect that duplicating the `externaldb_*` nodes under `global\resources` with another (unique) resource name e.g. `externaldb2_*` should work.

```
<global>
<resources>
  <externaldb_write>
    <connection>
      <use>externaldb_database</use>
    </connection>
  </externaldb_write>
  <externaldb_read>
    <connection>
      <use>externaldb_database</use>
    </connection>
  </externaldb_read>
  <externaldb_setup>
    <connection>
      <use>core_setup</use>
    </connection>
  </externaldb_setup>
  <externaldb_database>
    <connection>
      <host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
      <username><![CDATA[db_username]]></username>
      <password><![CDATA[db_password]]></password>
      <dbname><![CDATA[db_name]]></dbname>
      <model>mysql4</model>
      <type>pdo_mysql</type>
      <active>1</active>
    </connection>
  </externaldb_database>
  <externaldb2_write>
    <connection>
      <use>externaldb2_database</use>
    </connection>
  </externaldb2_write>
  <externaldb2_read>
    <connection>
      <use>externaldb2_database</use>
    </connection>
  </externaldb2_read>
  <externaldb2_setup>
    <connection>
      <use>core_setup</use>
    </connection>
  </externaldb2_setup>
  <externaldb2_database>
    <connection>
      <host><![CDATA[localhost2]]></host>
      <username><![CDATA[db2_username]]></username>
      <password><![CDATA[db2_password]]></password>
      <dbname><![CDATA[db2_name]]></dbname>
      <model>mysql4</model>
      <type>pdo_mysql</type>
      <active>1</active>
    </connection>
  </externaldb2_database>
</resources>
```

Comment: Thanks Jonathan for the prompt reply. However, I want to fetch data in Magento way (using/creating Magento models). After adding externaldb2 node, how can I use it in Magento models. As in the example link, externaldb node is used to define the model. How can I define model for externaldb2 similarly?

Comment: @chapagain, do the same thing, put the model in a different module, in said module setup the 2nd database as your resource, and you can do what you're trying to do... just invoke the model from the 2nd module through the 1st

Answer (score 5):

You can specify the resource used in the module's etc/config.xml file, so that a module will always use a certain data source or you can specify in the global config xml as described by the previous answer, then this connection will be used by default.

You can change the resource in your code:

```
$resource = Mage::getSingleton(‘core/resource’);
$conn     = $resource->getConnection(‘externaldb2_read’);
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you can't have models connecting to multiple database sources from within the same module.

What I've done, is create a parallel dummy module, that only contains the model that needs to connect to the alternate database.  So the module that does all the work is in one branch, and the dummy module to talk to the other database is separate.  Solves the problem beautifully, although it's not the most elegant solution... but it's not the least elegant either