# Can magento use different multiple database for product?

Tags: database, magento

I have multiple store in Magento, each store have different domain.

I'm wondering can Magento read 2 or more different databases, e.g for product and catalog for each store?

Because the default Magento just input all of products for each store in one database, I think this is very slow...

Can anybody help me?

Thanks

Regards

ian

Comment: Take a look @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654379/how-to-connect-multiple-external-databases-in-magento

Comment: hello, not an external database, but magento database, 1 management user but different database product for each store :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not fimilar with Magento, and I am not fond of using more than one database, but you can check out this artical here about it:

[How do you connect to multiple MySQL databases on a single webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274892/how-do-you-connect-to-multiple-mysql-databases-on-a-single-webpage)

Also you could just use different tables in a database and put in your query some thing like:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1")
```

anything like that

Comment: magento is not simply like that bro :)
but thanks anyway for answering my question ..

Comment: But why are you needing two databases and just not two tables?

Comment: Just impractical to use two different databases.

Comment: well.. as far as i know.. i think it's more easy to use two different table rather than using two table for product in magento..

Comment: I would suggest making a table for each store, not different databases. Due to linking multiple databases can be hectic.

Comment: I would suggest just reposting another question perhaps with more detail. And if your done on this page, just hit the check by this answer and start anew.