# How can I use the External Database connection In Magento?

Tags: php, mysql, magento-1.7, moodle

This is my core PHP code which is used in Magento.

```
        $model_moodle = mysql_connect("localhost","root","123456")  
            or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");       
        //select a database to work with
        $selected = mysql_select_db("moodle",$model_moodle) 
          or die("Could not select moodle");
        //execute the SQL query and return records
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM mdl_course where shortname ='".$data."'");        
        //fetch tha data from the database 
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {        
           $course_id = $row['id'];//display the results          
        }
        //echo "Cource id is=".$course_id;
        //close the connection
        mysql_close($model_moodle);
```

I need to Use this code but Using the Magento External Database Connection.
I am using the "Moodle" database in Magento . but I need the code for Magento way.

Comment: check this I think this will help..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654379/how-to-connect-multiple-external-databases-in-magento

Comment: Thank you @Rocksis But i think this is the Long Way....To Made the External Database Connection....!

Comment: try to ask your question http://magento.stackexchange.com here

Comment: Thank You So Much RS Sisodiya...!

Comment: also check this http://phpcmsframework.blogspot.in/2012/11/magento-creating-and-accessing-external.html
I think there is no shortcut

Comment: I found a awesome article over this question : http://www.solvingmagento.com/accessing-an-external-database-from-your-magento-module/ check it out it might help you. It has detailed explanations.

Answer (score 0):

Use this mysql command to connect to external database :

mysql -h clouddb.com -u root -p dbname;

It asks password for root, then enter password , Then you may login to your external DB!!